# Adding created_at and updated_at to LOAD DATA INFILE data

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table that I'm planning to populate from a CSV file. The file includes 22 columns and the table includes 24. The differences are `created_at` and `updated_at` fields at the end of the column list.

What I really want to happen is for each record to be created and for the last 2 columns to be defaulted.

I added the columns like so:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
  ADD created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  ADD updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
;
```

My loader script looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/my.csv'
    REPLACE INTO TABLE mytable
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
;
```

What I'd like, of course, is for the `created_at` and `updated_at` value to get set when a new record is inserted. If a record is ever replaced, the `updated_at` value should be replaced?

Possible? I'm using MariaDB 10.0.26 and both dates are always created with values of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Comment: Check the precise rules for `DEFAULT` on `TIMESTAMP`; they have changed over the versions.

Comment: @RickJames: Yeah, I _think_ I'm reading from the right places and have the right versions in place. I assume there's some nuance I'm missing (or something obvious I'm not smart enough to see), I just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps...
[Changelog for 10.0.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-1001-changelog/)
Skip down to "MDEV-452", where it says:

- MDEV-452 Add full support for auto-initialized/updated timestamp and datetime
- Generalized support for auto-updated and/or auto-initialized timestamp and datetime columns. This patch is a reimplementation of MySQL's "WL#5874: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DEFAULT for DATETIME columns". In order to ease future merges, this implementation reused few function and variable names from MySQL's patch, however the implementation is quite different.
- TODO: The only unresolved problem in this patch is the semantics of LOAD DATA for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns in the cases when there are missing or NULL columns. I couldn't fully comprehend the logic behind MySQL's behavior and its relationship with their own documentation, so I left the results to be more consistent with all other LOAD cases.
- The problematic test cases can be seen by running the test file function_defaults, and observing the test case differences. Those were left on purpose for discussion.

If you feel that there is still an issue with MariaDB, file a bug there.